# how to use golang runtime to print c struct's all fields by cgo

Tags: c, cgo

I have a C project which have many big structs, and I need to print these structs' detail values in the debugging phase. So I came up with an idea to use golang runtime to print these C structs' all the fields like the convenient way of golang print, such as: `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v)`. But it doesn't work after few times of tries. Below are my demo code:

main.go:

```
package main


/*
#include "test.h"

typedef struct {
    int id;
    unsigned int age;
}stu;

*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
}

//export PrintCStruct
func PrintCStruct(ptr interface{}) {
    u := &C.struct_user{}
    u.age = 90
    fmt.Printf("user:%+v type:%+v kind:%+v\n", u, reflect.ValueOf(u).Type(), reflect.TypeOf(u).Kind())

    s := C.stu{}
    s.id = 1
    s.age = 20
    fmt.Printf("stu:%+v type:%+v kind:%+v\n", s, reflect.ValueOf(s).Type(), reflect.TypeOf(s).Kind())

    fmt.Printf("C.user size:%v ptr size:%v\n", C.sizeof_struct_user, unsafe.Sizeof(ptr))

    //value := reflect.ValueOf(ptr)
    //fmt.Printf("ptr value:%+v ptr:%+v\n", value, ptr)  // panic here!!!
    //if reflect.ValueOf(ptr).CanInterface() {
    //  fmt.Printf("interface:%v\n", reflect.ValueOf(ptr).Interface())
    //}
}

//export returnInterface
func returnInterface() interface{} {
    u := C.struct_user{}
    u.id = 12
    u.age = 80
    u.score = 100
    return u
}
```

compile command: `go build -buildmode=c-archive -o libcstructpp.a ./main.go`

test.h:

```
#ifndef _TEST_H_
#define _TEST_H_

struct user {
    int id;
    int age;
    int score;
};

#endif
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "libcstructpp.h"
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    struct user u = { .id = 20, .age = 20, .score = 100 };
    GoInterface goInterface = {.t = "*C.struct_user", .v = &u};
    printf("u:%p\n", &u);
    PrintCStruct(goInterface);

    GoInterface goInter = returnInterface();
    printf("t:%p, type:%s, v:%p, value:%d\n", goInter.t, (char*)(goInter.t), goInter.v, *(int*)goInter.v); // the GoInterface returned by returnInterface is not expected as my  expectation
    char* p = goInter.t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        printf("%02x", p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

compile command: `gcc ./test.c -I. -L. -lcstructpp -lpthread -o test`

run command:
./test
run result:

```
u:0x7ffd163c2fd4
user:&{id:0 age:90 score:0} type:*main._Ctype_struct_user kind:ptr
stu:{id:1 age:20} type:main._Ctype_struct___0 kind:struct
C.user size:12 ptr size:16
t:0x55c86a8bac80, type:
                       , v:0xc4200900a0, value:12
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
```

I what to pass the GoInterface struct into the function PrintCStruct, and the go runtime will translate the GoInterface to golang interface which go runtime must have parsed the interface's real layer struct and then I can invoke `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", ptr)` to print the C struct. If there is no way to do like this, I have to write a special print function for each specical C struct like:

```
//export PrintUser
func PrintUser(ptr uintptr) {
    // convert the pointer to struct
    user, ok := (*C.struct_user)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr))
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf("user:%+v\n", *user)
    }
    // do something else
    // ......
}
```